# Операции присвоения и инкремента, объясните что не так?

Tags: java

Есть небольшой фрагмент кода на понимание java

```
int i = 0;
i = i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

что я ожидаю увидеть:

1. -i присвоили значение 0
2. значение i (то есть ноль) и присвоили к i
3. теперь 0. Увеличили инкрементацией значенение i - получили 1

Ожидаю что получу в консоли 1, но получаю ноль. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нужно прояснить как минимум два момента.

1. У оператора присваивания (`=`) приоритет ниже чем у операции инкремента (`++`).

   По спецификации Java ([§15.2.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)) оператор присваивания сначала обрабатывает правую часть и затем присваивает. Так что шаги 2 и 3 нужно будет поменять местами.
2. Оператор постфиксного инкремента возвращает предыдущее значение переменной.

   По спецификации Java ([§15.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)) оператор (`i++`) прибавляет 1 к переменной, но в качестве результата операции возвращает значение до увеличения переменной. В этом отличие от префиксной формы оператора (`++i`).

   Чтобы было проще разобраться используйте разные переменные для увеличения и присваивания, так сложнее запутаться:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   int a = i++; //a = 0, т.к. возвращается значение до увеличения
   //i = 1, переменная увеличивается

   int j = 0;
   int b = ++j; //b = 1, т.к. возвращается значение после увеличения
   //j = 1, переменная увеличивается
   ```

Теперь можно построить описание того, что здесь происходит:

1. i присвоили значение 0
2. Обрабатывается правая часть выражения. Оператор (`i++`) увеличивает значение переменной (`i=1`) и возвращает значение до увеличения (`0`).
3. Выполняется оператор присваивания: `i` присваивается значение, возвращенное из правой части — 0 (`i=0`).

Answer (score 2):

У инкремента в Java существует две формы, постфиксная:

```
i++
```

и префиксная:

```
++i
```

В постфиксной форме сначала производится операция присваивания, а потом уже инкрементирования. Поэтому ваша переменная так и не поменяла своё значение.

Чтобы выражение заработало, нужно использовать именно префиксную форму, она гарантирует первоочерёдность инкрементирования при операциях с переменной.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = i++;
```

---

```
__temp = i;
i = i + 1;
i = __temp;
```

Все манипуляции с правой частью происходят *до* присвоения значения левой части.

Comment: Как раз наоборот: все манипуляции с правой частью проводятся после присвоения. Таким образом, сначала присваивается ноль, а потом  уже производится инкрементирование, результат которого ингнорируется.

Comment: Тут просто надо заметить, что в выражении `i = i++;` переменная которая слева это не совсем та переменная что справа. В этом и путаются начинающие.

Comment: @coolsv Еще раз наоборот - и вернемся к тому, что я сказал.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Это та же самая переменная. Прошу Вас убрать этот комментарий из-под моего ответа ).

Comment: @Igor Что я должен убрать и с какого перепугу?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Вы ничего не должны. Пугаться не следует. Я обратился к Вам с просьбой убрать запутывающее объяснение. Наш третий коллега, который отметился под моим ответом, тоже неправ.

Comment: @Igor не совсем понимаю о чем вы. Я в чем-то не прав? Вы сами зачем-то при объяснении в ответе ввели новую переменную, да еще и в си-стиле чтобы показать, что переменная `i` слева это не совсем та же переменная `i`, что справа.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець это не введение третьей переменной. Так работает постфиксный инкремент под капотом, если вы изучали это